# The Difference Between 'Positively' And 'Certainly'

Tags: word-meaning

I can't distinguish 'positively' from 'certainly'.

According to Cambridge Dictionary, one of the definitions of ['positively'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/positively) is: certainly.

> positively
>   adverb
>   positively adverb (CERTAINLY)
>   without a doubt; certainly:
>   • I positively will be there.

However, I know that the usage of 'positively' differs from 'certainly'.

For example, those sentences cited from a Reading Test in an FCE Test: 'Just imagine a date without paper,' reads one advertisement for a Finnish paper company. It adds,

> 'You almost (1)____ see our products every day.' And they are right. [...]

It provides me four options:

> A. Positively; B. Obviously; C. Certainly; D. Absolutely.

As far as I knew, the key was C. Certainly. Can you explain why we choose C instead of A?

Comment: We can use 'positively' to mean 'certainly'. The police have positively identified the body found yesterday in the river. – Michael Harvey 1 hour ago

Comment: "Almost certainly" is a standard phrase meaning "very probably".

Comment: I'm voting "Unclear", because there are many different contexts where the two words are interchangeable, but *many others* where they're not. And some of those "differences" are a matter of opinion, whereas some are beyond dispute (on the grounds of syntax, semantics, idiomacy, or some combination thereof).

Comment: Idiomatically, the advice to a snooker player is always *Strike the ball **positively***, never ***...certainly***.

Comment: You would only say 'You almost certainly see our products every day.'. You would never say ''You almost positively see our products every day.'.

Comment: Just just confuse matters, you can be *positively certain* about something too.

Comment: I repeat, "almost certainly" is a fixed phrase. The 'almost' would be a clue in the multiple-choice test.

Comment: Please include those details (the exam question, research, etc.) in your posts (not the comments). You can [edit] your post at any time. This will make your question clearer and protect your post from down/close votes. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of this exam question, I would say that the key is *almost*. *Almost certainly* is a common expression, where as *almost positively* is not. From [nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almost+positively%2C+almost+certainly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calmost%20positively%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20certainly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Calmost%20positively%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20certainly%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

*Almost certainly* roughly means *very likely*. Here's an example I dug up from Lexico:

> [certainly](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/certainly)
>   adverb
>   [sentence adverb]
>   1 Used to emphasize the speaker's belief that what is said is true.
>   *‘There are others as well, of course, and one of them will almost certainly come true.’*

Now, lack of usage does not mean "incorrect". However, *almost positively* is not used in the same way as *almost certainly*. I can't say that *almost positively* has one particular or common meaning. If I force it into the exam sentence, then my first thought was that it sounded like you almost see the products in a *positive way* (as opposed to *negatively*, *in a negative way*). The meaning did not involve any kind of certainty.